# What is best way to perform jQuery .change()

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have 2 separate scripts that essentially do the same thing. I built them over time and just discovered I am using a couple different means to get to the same result.

I want to standardize and use the best practices method in both cases.

One way I test a change event is this:

```
$('input[name="status"]').change(function() {});
```

Another way I am testing a change event is this:

```
$("#email").bind("change", function(e) {});
```

Which way is best? What is the difference between the 2?

Thanks for helping me understand this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before jQuery 1.7, `change()` was [simply a short cut](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.4/src/event.js#L1178-1197) for `bind("change")`.

As of 1.7 however, [`on()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/event.js#L974-976) was introduced, and is preferred to `bind()`. That now means `change()` is a shortcut for `on("change")`, and in fact all `bind()` calls will now call [`on()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/event.js#L974-976) internally.

In short, they do the same thing. I find the explicit use of `on()` (or `bind()`) preferable, but as long as you're consistent throughout your code base, I don't see any real differences.

One could argue that using `change()` over `on("change")` is "better", as a typo in the word "change" would throw a parse error in the first instance ("undefined is not a function"), but would fail silently with `on()`... but obviously your unit tests would catch that, right? ;).

Comment: So @Matt, my code syntax needs to look like this `$("#email").on("change", function(e) {});` ?