# Change table cell style if checkbox is checked

Tags: css, checkbox, html-table

I have a table and I want each cell to have a red background if the cell is disabled, and blue if is enabled. So I have a inserted an invisible checkbox in each cell. When I have labels instead of  a table, it works ok (see [example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles) here), but it´s not working with a table.

HTML:

```
  <table id="hours">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="tdh00"><input type="checkbox" id="h00"></td>
        <td id="tdh01"><input type="checkbox" id="h01"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] { visibility: hidden; }
#hours input[type=checkbox]:checked  + #tdh00 { background-color: #265BFA; }
#hours input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) + #tdh00 { background-color: #FA2421; }
```

Comment: You html and css both are invalid. And form is not part of table. So table is sibling of input element. you can perform things on table when checkbox is selected. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crazyrohila/hTxZS/)

Comment: Can you provide a visual to illustrate what you are after? Also, are you sure that a `table` is appropriate markup? It may well be simpler to achieve what you want by altering the markup.

Comment: @crazyrohila - a `tr` can only contain `td` and/or `th` elements.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez Thanks, I was thinking to write that, but was not so sure. I started my life after divs, so table not much of experience. :)

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez I want something like this: http://html-color-codes.info/ I need a table of 24 hours and 7 days, and you enable the hours you are not busy. Red hours you are busy, blue hours you are not. JS solutions are valid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your markup as it stands, this is not going to work. You are using the `+` (sibling) selector, but your table cells are not siblings of your checkboxes. In the example you gave, the markup is:

```
<div class="slideOne">  
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideOne" name="check" />
    <label for="slideOne"></label>
</div>
```

Yours is:

```
<td id="tdh00"><input type="checkbox" id="h00"></td>
```

So, you are attempting to style the parent based on the state of one its child elements, which is not currently possible with CSS alone.

**EDIT**

Check out [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/THuat/). That fiddle adds the `label` back in (which will help with accessibility), and positions it in such a way that it visually does what you're after. The markup needs to be:

```
<table id="hours">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="tdh00">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="h00">
                <label for="h00">Label</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="tdh01">
             <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="h01">
                <label for="h01">Label</label>
              </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And the CSS:

```
table {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 0;
}

td > div { position: relative; }

input[type=checkbox] { visibility: hidden; }

label {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: red;
    text-indent: -999em;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked  + label { background-color: #265BFA; }
```

The extra `div` in each table cell is necessary, because Firefox can't handle positioning things relative to `td` elements.

Browser support is good, but only IE9+ is supported because we're using the `:checked` pseudo-class. You'll get better support with a JavaScript-based solution, but I'd argue that this is a great candidate for progressive enhancement.

**EDIT 2**

If support for old IE is a requirement, then you'll need to resort to JavaScript. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/jSbKJ/) using jQuery.

The JavaScript just adds a class of `active` to the table cell: the bulk of the work is still done with CSS.

```
$("#hours input").on('change', function(){
    var checkbox = $(this),
        tableCell = checkbox.parents('td');

    checkbox.is(':checked') ?
        tableCell.removeClass('active') :
        tableCell.addClass('active');
}).change();
```

The HTML remains the same, and the CSS differs only slightly with these lines replacing the `:checked` pseudo-class:

```
td { background-color: #265BFA; }
.active { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: I don´t require a non-JS solution. I thought it was easier... but i think i was wrong. Any example to do this with JS?

Comment: Finally worked EDIT 2 after wrapping in a $("document").ready(function. Also I replaced .on('change', function() to  .change(function

Comment: What version of jQuery are you working with? As of 1.7, `change` just calls `on`, prior to that it was calling `bind`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995638/what-is-best-way-to-perform-jquery-change. So, I believe the best solution is my original.

Comment: I'd also messed up the links in my answer. The jQuery version is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/jSbKJ/

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js With .on down´t work (the event doesn´t get fired). And with .change, only works if the checkbox is visible... Did you managed to get your code work?

Comment: That fiddle works for me, using the above code, in Chrome, Firefox and IE(10).

Comment: I saw the source code of  jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/jSbKJ, and it wraps the code in a $(window).load(function(){. I´ve done the same, and it works. Without the .load doesn´t work. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Good answer, but I suggest using toggleClass rather than removeClass/addClass.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below this is the solution with **JQuery** :

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/138/

**HTML :**

```
<table id="hours" border="1">
 <tbody>
    <tr><td id="tdh00"><input type="checkbox" id="h00"></td><td id="tdh01"><input type="checkbox" id="h01"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

**CSS :**

```
input[type=checkbox] { visibility: hidden; }
```

**JQuery :**

```
$("#hours td").each(function(e){ 
    var ele = $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]');
    var flag = ele.prop('checked');
    if(flag)
    {
        ele.prop('checked', false);
        $(this).css("background", "#265BFA");
    }
    else
    {
        ele.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).css("background", "#FA2421");
    }
});

$("#hours td").click(function(e){ 
    var ele = $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]');
    var flag = ele.prop('checked');
    if(flag)
    {
        ele.prop('checked', false);
        $(this).css("background", "#265BFA");
    }
    else
    {
        ele.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).css("background", "#FA2421");
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this as it stands is that only the `click` event is given, so on initial page load the background of each cell will not be changed to the correct colour.

Comment: That's quite a lot of repetition, and as you're using the click event it's not very accessible. For a different approach, take a look at my new answer. You don't really want to be manipulating the CSS directly  in your JS, but should just use it to toggle a class.