# Selecting an object with jQuery after a change function, modified the html structure of the element that needed selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code (playing with some selects).

After the first change function, the second change function does not work:

```
        jQuery('.toPopSelect').change(function(){
            console.log("hey");
        });
```

**I think it's because the first change function replaces some html and jQuery can't select the .toPopSelect class after.**

Any idea why is this happening? is there a way around it?

```
    <select class="theSelect">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>

    <div class="toPopulate">
        <select class="toPopSelect">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>




jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('.theSelect').change(function(){
            jQtoPopulate = jQuery('.toPopulate');
            jQtoPopulate.empty();
            jQtoPopSelect = jQuery('.toPopSelect');
            v = jQuery(this).val();

            if ( v == 1) {
                console.log("ues")
                jQtoPopulate.html('<input type="text" size="60"><\/input>');
            } else {
                jQtoPopulate.html('<select class="toPopSelect"><option value="1">1<\/option><option value="2">2<\/option><option value="3">3<\/option><option value="4">4<\/option><option value="5">5<\/option><\/select>');

                jQtoPopSelect.append('<option value="6">6<\/option>');
            }

        });

        jQuery('.toPopSelect').change(function(){
            console.log("hey");
        });

    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Great explanation here also... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995638/what-is-best-way-to-perform-jquery-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as you say. Because you're changing the DOM when you change the first select element, it's writing over the second select element, and therefore the element to which your `console.log("hey");` event handler is attached no longer exists.

When your code runs this:

```
jQuery('.toPopSelect').change(function(){
            console.log("hey");
});
```

what it's doing is attaching the handler to all elements that match `.toPopSelect` **at the time that the code is run**. It isn't attaching an event handler to all and every `.toPopSelect` that will ever occur within your page.

Therefore you can reattach the event handler after changing the DOM:

```
jQuery('.theSelect').change(function(){
    // stuff that changes DOM here

    jQuery('.toPopSelect').change(function(){
        console.log("hey");
    });
});
```

Another thing you can do is use:

```
$('.toPopulate').on('change', '.toPopSelect', function(){
    console.log("hey");
});
```

This assigns an event handler to `.toPopulate` but will only be trigger by events matching the second argument (`.toPopSelect`).  See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Note that if you change or remove `.toPopulate` from the DOM then this will also no longer apply. (Basically choose the nearest ancestor of `.toPopSelect` that will remain within the DOM.)

Comment: Great explanation, but won't the reattachment take place each time the first change event happens? I belive Krishna's solution would be more efficient. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: yeah, i included both solutions just to cover all the bases. As to which is more efficient, that depends on a bunch of factors but in a lot of cases I imagine that the difference isn't worth worrying about. Personally, I would go with attaching the event once to `.toPopulate`, then you don't have to worry about it so much.

Comment: I've selected your question as the accepted answer since the explanations are complete.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a listener like this because you add code after.

The jsFiddle to illustrate that : http://jsfiddle.net/s6MVQ/

```
$(document).on('change', '.toPopSelect', function(){
    alert("ok");
});
```

More information on : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Ty for answering, I get an error - ReferenceError: change is not defined

Comment: I have make to error :o. I corrected it. it's "change" and not just change. But my jsFiddle works from the beginning :)

Comment: @DanyD - wrap 'change' with quotes

Comment: I've felt that BYossarian is more complete, this is why I have selected his answer as the accepted one. I have up voted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do event delegation properly. Since `.toPopSelect` is created dynamically, you have to handle event in the following way. [jquery .on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('change', '.toPopSelect', function(){
    console.log("hey");
});
```

Even better (for performance) if you could replace `document` with a static outer container's class/id

Comment: I've felt that BYossarian is more complete, this is why I have selected his answer as the accepted one. I have up voted your answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('.theSelect').change(function(){
            jQtoPopulate = jQuery('.toPopulate');
            jQtoPopulate.empty();
            jQtoPopSelect = jQuery('.toPopSelect');
            v = jQuery(this).val();

            if ( v == 1) {
                console.log("ues")
                jQtoPopulate.html('<input type="text" size="60"><\/input>');
            } else {
                jQtoPopulate.html('<select class="toPopSelect"><option value="1">1<\/option><option value="2">2<\/option><option value="3">3<\/option><option value="4">4<\/option><option value="5">5<\/option><\/select>');

                jQtoPopSelect.append('<option value="6">6<\/option>');
            }

        });

        var c = $(document);
        c.delegate(".toPopSelect","change",function(){ alert("hey"); });

    });
```