# JQuery event handler with or without on?

Tags: jquery

If I have a dropdown in my html document looking like this:

```
<select id="myDropdown">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
```

and I want to hook up on the change event with JQuery, then both of these approaches seem to work with JQuery:

```
$("#myDropdown").change(function () {
   // Do something
});
```

and

```
$('#myDropdown').on('change', function () {
   // Do something
});
```

What is the difference between these two, and is one of them to prefer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is best way to perform jQuery .change()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995638/what-is-best-way-to-perform-jquery-change)

Comment: @LinkinTED I believe this question is about event binding in general, not only concerning change()

Comment: not a duplicate. Here he is using `on`.

Comment: @Alex __As of 1.7 however, on() was introduced... That now means change() is a shortcut for on("change")__

Comment: Generelly speaking, calling `on()` on the set of matched elements that the event will be bound to (not like delegation), the only main difference is that you can switch off the event using `off()`

Comment: but you can still switch off by using `$().change(function(){})` (empty handler)

Comment: @OP: just have a read on directly and delegated events on the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

See, both are called event binding, there is no difference but `.on()` has some advantages over **direct event binding** (*don't have right word for it*).

The advantage with `.on()` method is `event delegation`, which is useful when you have a dynamically created element in the page. It has a bit specific syntax but uses `.on()` method:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

There is another advantage of `.on()` method is, if you have bound any event on a selector then that event can be called off with `.off()` method.

Also want to mention that `.on()/.off()` has replaced the `.bind()/.unbind()` methods and about event delegation it has replaced `.live()/.die()`.

Comment: its actually called direct and delegated events, so you were correct ;-)

Comment: @rafat not more than direct binding would have, does it?

Answer (score 1):

`$.on(...)`, is much more powerful approach since it allows you to attach only one event listener on a container, and provide it with matching selectors, instead of attaching tons of event listeners... 
For example, this code:

```
$('#container .item').click(function(){ ... });
```

**VS**

```
$('#container').on('click', '.item', function(){ ... });
```

The `.click()` approach attaches event listener to every `.item` element- possibly A LOT of them on page...

The `.on('click'...)` approach only attach one event listener to the `#container` element, and on every click it checks if the element that triggered the event is an `.item` element, and if so- executes the callback function.

The `.on(...)` function also "catch" `.item` elements that are not on the page when this piece of js runs, not like the `.click()` method that only binding currently existing `.item` elements, and you would need to bind it manually if you later inject newly created `.item` elements to the page.